# Pass variable from Recyclerview-Holder to Mainactivity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, main-activity

I tried a lot of things but I can't get it to work... I try to pass this String Variable (when i click Item in RecyclerView) to my MainActivity. 
What works bad is calling the function (OnRecyclerViewItemClick) and changing the variable(GetUrlFromItem). My version of Android Studio is 2.3.3

I really need do this:

My RecyclerView:

```
public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView titulo;
    Button playbtn01;
    List<Fuente> ListaObjeto;

    public viewHolder(View itemView,List<Fuente> datos) {
        super(itemView);

        ListaObjeto = datos;

        titulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.texto);
        playbtn01 = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.playbtn00);

        playbtn01.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        Fuente objeto = ListaObjeto.get(position);

        if (view.getId() == playbtn01.getId()) {

            MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity:
            mainActivity.OnRecyclerViewItemClick();      /// initiate Void in Main
            mainActivity.GetUrlFromItem = objeto.GetUrl; //Change Variable of Main

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public String GetUrlFromItem; 

    public void OnRecyclerViewItemClick() {
        if (GetUrlFromItem  == "..."){
            doSomething...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two big problems that I see.

The first is how you get a `MainActivity` instance to work with. In your question, you have this line of code:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity:
```

Calling `new` is going to do exactly what it sounds like: create a *new* instance of the `MainActivity` class. You do not want a new instance! You want your alive and running instance.

There are a handful of ways to get ahold of your alive and running `MainActivity`, but probably the simplest one for now is going to be casting your `ViewHolder`'s `itemView`'s `Context`. So instead of the above, write something like this:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) itemView.getContext();
```

The second big problem is in the next two lines:

```
mainActivity.OnRecyclerViewItemClick();
mainActivity.GetUrlFromItem = objeto.GetUrl;
```

The problem here is the order of these two statements. Because you invoke `mainActivity.OnRecyclerViewItemClick()` **before** setting the value of `mainActivity.GetUrlFromItem`, the value will not be updated when `OnRecyclerViewItemClick()` is executed.

Simply swap the order of these two lines.